# SMART-status: Reallocated_Sector_Ct should I be worried?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I'm wondering if I should be woried about these SMART values on my harddrive:

[image: Screenshot of Smart Attributes, grey on white text. Reallocated sector count is highlighted in pink]
and statistics:

[image: Screenshot of Statistics]

Comment: Are the 'worrysome' numbers static are are they increasing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto interpret SMART-Attributes?](https://superuser.com/questions/429639/howto-interpret-smart-attributes)

Comment: they have since last time I tested(initially) it only had 38 reported Uncorrectable errors, but this is the first time I ran the long test too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be worried, but you SHOULD BE REPLACING YOUR drive.   It is clearly showing early signs of failure.

Comment: that sucks, it only has about 600hours of use... guess I shouldnt have bought the seagate....

Comment: Its luck of the draw - I've had much better experience with WD then Seagate.  If you want reliability you really need to get an SSD - they are typically 10x more reliable then hard drives (but be aware when they fail they usually do so without warning)

Comment: What model drive is it ?

Comment: I usually buy WD as well...I got this one because it was the only 2.5" 2TB drive at the time. it's a ST2000LM015-2E8174

Comment: 140 out of 200 max. Model Family:     Western Digital Blue Mobile
Device Model:     WDC WD5000LPCX-24VHAT0

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> Reallocated Sectors Count - Potential indicator of imminent
> electromechanical failure.

And definition:

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a
> read/write/verification error, it marks that sector as "reallocated"
> and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
> process is also known as remapping, and reallocated sectors are called
> "remaps". The raw value normally represents a count of the bad sectors
> that have been found and remapped. Thus, the higher the attribute
> value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This allows a
> drive with bad sectors to continue operation; however, a drive which
> has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail
> in the near future.[3] While primarily used as a metric of the life
> expectancy of the drive, this number also affects performance. As the
> count of reallocated sectors increases, the read/write speed tends to
> become worse because the drive head is forced to seek to the reserved
> area whenever a remap is accessed. If sequential access speed is
> critical, the remapped sectors can be manually marked as bad blocks in
> the file system in order to prevent their use.

It happened on something that I recently purchased:

```
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue Mobile
Device Model:     WDC WD5000LPCX-24VHAT0
```